# Proving nonintegrability of a function of a random variable with a shift

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convex-analysis

Let $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a nonnegative, convex and coercive function (i.e. $\lim_{|t| \to \infty}g(t) = \infty$) such that $g(0) = 0$. Let $X$ be a random variable. Is it true that

If $\mathbb{E}[g(X)] = \infty$, then $\mathbb{E}[g(X - s)] = \infty$ for any $s \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You are proving nonintegrability, not integrability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.  The stated conditions on the function $g$ do not rule out this kind of counterexample.  Let $g(x)=\exp(e^x)-b$ for all $x>K$,
for some  positive constant $K$, and some constant $b$ to be chosen later. Let $Z$ be a random variable supported on $[A,\infty)$, such that $\mathbb{E} Z<\infty$ but $ \mathbb{E}Z^2=\infty$. (With density function proportional to $x^{-3}$, say, for $x>A$.)  Then the random variable $X = \log(2\log Z)$ has the property that $g(X) = Z^2-b$ but with the choice $s=\log 2$, we have  $g(X-s) = Z-b$.

This leaves a few details to fill in, such as how to define $g$ for $x<K$ and how to chose $K$, $b$, and $A$.